# Spark 2.0: Flatten Piped data in Spark Dataframe into individual rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DF with, say 10 columns, one of the columns has String data with Pipe as the delimiter.

```
+-------------+
|offer_ids    |
+-------------+
|9|10|11|12|  |
+-------------+
```

I need to store this in the RDMBS, which has an INT column and each of the above values (|9|10|11|12|) would be a separate record, with all other columns in the DF remain the same.

for eg. the final statement in,

```
 inputDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc
```

should be,

```
insert into <table name> values (<values for other columns>, 9)
insert into <table name> values (<values for other columns>, 10)
insert into <table name> values (<values for other columns>, 11)
insert into <table name> values (<values for other columns>, 12)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

explode() function can be used for that:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(List(("a", "b", 1, 2, 3) )).toDF("a", "b", "d1", "d2", "d3")
df.selectExpr("a", "b", "explode(array(d1,d2,d3))").show

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|col|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  1|
|  a|  b|  2|
|  a|  b|  3|
+---+---+---+
```